Is the danger of space radiation overstated?
I've heard from some people that it is and it can be mitigated my mass and/or magnetic shielding. Magnetic shields could be powered by any spacecraft that used any form of nuclear propulsion involving a reactor. Does this mean it actually isn't as much of an issue as muscle wastage , psychological problems and management of life support resources (food water and air)

More mass = less delta-V, lower speed, longer voyage and longer radiation exposure.
Magnetic shielding = huge magnets meaning more mass, etc (see above). Magnetic shielding only deflects charged particles, not high energy photons or neutral particles.
Radiation is a major issue in extended space voyages beyond LEO. If you want to know if the danger is "overstated", please quote the statement you are referring to.
See Does human sensitivity to radiation impose a maximum distance on interstellar voyages regardless of radiation shielding or speed?

They say that currently we couldn't even make it to mars and back without astronauts taking more radiation than NASA allows in entire careers.
